# Add string to resource at runtime using WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to add strings to STRINGTABLE resource at runtime?
I have a plugin which is connected to host application, which expects strings delivered with LoadString method. On my end, I'm able to prepare data only at runtime (usually once during start-up). I'm preparing DLGTEMPLATE structures on the fly already, is there similar way to deal with STRINGTABLE?
Any other solution?

Thanks,

Comment: Nope. You can add a resource to another PE file(dll,exe), but you can't modify a file with itself.

Comment: OK. It might be a workaround. Any tips on how to create and add resources to such file during run-time?

Comment: Yeah, sure. If you need to change fileA.ext, then you can do that with fileB.ext - You CANNOT, and I repeat, can not use fileA.ext to change fileA.ext. If you've not read it, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728641(v=vs.71).aspx - The only hack I can think of is to hook LoadString, returning actual string resources where appropriate, returning your own strings in other cases. If you know you need a string, why not do as was intended and compile it in? The question smells of (a) bad-design or (b) an attempted hack of a (someone else's) program. :shrugs:

Comment: Thank you very much. You might be right about bad-design, since I'm trying to get behavior from host application it was not designed for. Is it possible to compile a resource script file using WinAPI without rc.exe?

Comment: A pleasure. As far as I know, all you need to add a resource to a (Portable Executable - PE) file is the function I mentioned and it's header/lib file (not sure which they are). If you want a resource compiler to turn .RC files into .RES ones, I use the one that comes with MinGW. You get the whole compiler suite with an IDE for about 70MB if you download Code::Blocks with MinGW. You can also get MinGW on it's own - it's probably around half of that or less. Of course, you can also get something like ResHacker - to add resources to an exe or dll. A couple hundred kb - standalone tool. :)

Answer (score 0):

As enhzflep suggested, I went with updating a separate PE file. It took some try and error to get string update right so I'm posting here my solution.

One note: I'm writing strings sequentially. It's important to update resource with chunk of 16 strings, so writing strings with predefined IDs would involve writing some empty strings.

```
const int RESOURCE_STRING_START = 1 << 14; /// custom start ID value
std::vector<std::wstring> m_resource_strings;

/// add strings ///

HANDLE lib_handle = BeginUpdateResource( library_name, TRUE);

size_t string_section_size = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m_resource_strings.size(); i++)
    string_section_size += m_resource_strings[i].length() * sizeof(WCHAR);

HGLOBAL heap = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_ZEROINIT, string_section_size); 
if (!heap) {
    return false;
}
/// Create temporary memory pool ///
WORD* heap_start = (WORD*)GlobalLock(heap);
if (!heap_start) {
    return false;
}
WORD* pos = NULL;

for (int i = 0; i < m_resource_strings.size(); i+=16)
{
    pos = heap_start;
    const int section = 1 + ((RESOURCE_STRING_START + i) >> 4);
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
    {
        if ( i+j < m_resource_strings.size() ) {
            std::wstring& str = m_resource_strings[j+i];
            *pos++ = str.length(); /// Write string length
            memcpy( pos, str.data(), str.length() * sizeof(WCHAR) ); /// Copy string
            pos += str.length();
        }
        else *pos++ = 0;
    }
    if (!UpdateResource(lib_handle, RT_STRING, (LPTSTR)(ULONG_PTR)section, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), heap_start, DWORD(pos) - DWORD(heap_start) ))
    {
        GlobalFree(heap);
        return false;
    }
}
GlobalFree(heap);

if (!EndUpdateResource( lib_handle, FALSE )) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This does not look complete. You should have added `BeginUpdateResource` and `EndUpdateResource` as well.